# How to get a select to show values in svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a select in my svelte app. I cannot get it to display it's initial value (*default_car*) or, after I have clicked on a car, the *selected_car*

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ab11a3b72eb6455bbc125a3edc1a6245?version=3.46.6)

**App.svelte**

```
<Car {cars} on:message={carChanged} />
<div>
    <button on:click={getDataStore}>Get data</button>
</div>

<script>
    import Car from './Cars.svelte'
    import { getBlankCars, getCarData } from './store.js'

    let cars = getBlankCars();
    let car;

    function carChanged(event) {
        car = event.detail.value;
        console.log('selected car:', car);
    }

    function getDataStore() {
        cars = getCarData();
    }
</script>
```

**Cars.svelte**

```
<select bind:value={selected_car} on:click={selectCar}>
    {#each car_list as car}
        <option value={car}>
            {car}
        </option>
    {/each}
</select>

<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    let started = false;
    export let cars;
    $cars = $cars;

    let car_list;
    $: car_list = carList($cars);

    let default_car = 'BMW';

    let selected_car;
    $: selected_car = getInitialCar($cars)
    $: selected_car = default_car

    function getInitialCar() {
        if (!started) {
            selected_car = default_car;
            if (selected_car) {
                started = true;
                selectCar();
            }
        }
        selected_car = default_car
    }

    function carList(cars) {
        let car_list = [];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(cars)) {
            car_list.push(key);
        }
        return car_list;
    }

    function selectCar() {
        dispatch('message', {
            value: selected_car
        });
    }
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

let blank_cars = {}
let raw_cars = {'Audi': 'red', 'Aston Martin': 'silver', 'BMW':'blue', 'Bugatti': 'black', 'Hillman': 'green'}

export function getBlankCars() {
    return writable(blank_cars)
}

export function getCarData() {
    return writable(raw_cars)
}
```

What can I do to get the select to display the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can reduce the code in `Cars.svelte` to this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/714f6f77ffea452aba76c7ba8c78e3e7?version=3.46.6) - does this function the way you want it to?
Three things to mention

- if you have an object as store value and want to display the content in an `{#each}` loop you don't have to generate a new array, but can directly iterate inside each with `{#each Object.keys($cars) as car}` or `{#each Object.entries($cars) as [key, value]}`
- change `on:click` to `on:change={selectCar}`
- the `<script>` block below the html is unusual ~ the more common order (like in the [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/)) is script - html - style/css

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    export let cars;

    let selected_car = 'BMW'; // set default value here

    function selectCar() {
        dispatch('message', {
            value: selected_car
        });
    }
</script>

<select bind:value={selected_car} on:change={selectCar}>
<!--    reduce code by directly iterating $cars via Object.entries/.keys/.values(obj) -->
    {#each Object.keys($cars) as car}
    <option value={car}>
        {car}
    </option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your constructive help. In what way is the script "unusual"?

Comment: @Psionman I mean the order inside the component. You have first the html part followed by the `<script>` tag. I think the common structure is script - html - css (but in the end it's just a matter of taste ~ for me it's unusual and I need to switch)

Comment: I understand - I'm new to svelte and learning how to use it idiomatically

Comment: Sure, I shouldn't have put it as one of the main points but as a side node... wasn't more than a remark to make aware of it - functionally it changes nothing

Comment: Just for interest sake, the [svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/adding-data) places script above html :)